# Display A 'Div' Depending On Selection Of Checkbox Value From Another Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a issue. I have an `asp.net webform` which has a process which stores the data in a `session`. The issue I can't resolved is that on one of the pages it displays all the details entered throughout the process but one section in only needed to be displayed depending on the selection from my `checkboxlist`.

**HTML for my `checkboxlist`**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="Services" CssClass="CheckboxList">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All services" Value="All services"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Site content uploading only" Value="Site content uploading only"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Site content &amp; layout checking" Value="Site content &amp; layout checking"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Testing on various browsers" Value="Testing on various browsers"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Testing all website functionality" Value="Testing all website functionality"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Responsive design (Design/Implemtation only)" Value="Responsive design (Design/Implemtation only)"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Responsive design (Testing only)" Value="Responsive design (Testing only)"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**Code behind for the above which stores the selections in the `session`**

```
private void SessionSaving()
{
    List<string> selections = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem listItem in Services.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
        {
            selections.Add(listItem.Value);
        }
    }

    Session["Step02Services"] = selections;
}
```

**HTML for my confirmation page**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="Step04BrowsersLabel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Browser(s) to check on:"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 form-control-static">
        <%= string.Join(", <br />",((List<string>)Session["Step04Browsers"]).ToArray()) %>

        <% if (Session["Step04OtherField"] != "")
        {%>
            <br />    
            <%=Session["Step04OtherField"] %>
        <%} %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want the above section to be displayed if any of the following scenarios checked checkboxes happen:

- Site content uploading only
- Site content & layout checking only
- Site content uploading & Site content & layout checking only

I tried the following `if`, and it doesn't always displays for me. If I remove the `||'s` and just use the first line it hides it for me. If I select the "Site content uploading only" checkbox and another checkbox it also displays if for me (which is correct).

```
if (string.Join("", ((List<string>)Session["Step02Services"]).ToArray()) != "Site content & layout checking"
    || string.Join(", <br />", ((List<string>)Session["Step02Services"]).ToArray()) != "Site content & layout checking"
    || string.Join("", ((List<string>)Session["Step02Services"]).ToArray()) != "Site content & layout checking" && string.Join(", <br />", ((List<string>)Session["Step02Services"]).ToArray()) != "Site content & layout checking")
```

How do I write/correct my `if` above?

**My fix was to the HTML on the confirmation page as shown below**

```
if (Session["Step04Browsers"] != null)
{    
<div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Step04BrowsersLabel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Browser(s) to check on:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 form-control-static">
            <%= string.Join(", <br />",((List<string>)Session["Step04Browsers"]).ToArray()) %>

            <% if (Session["Step04OtherField"] != "")
            {%>
                <br />    
                <%=Session["Step04OtherField"] %>
            <%} %>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can shorten the value of the checkbox's and keep the text for readability purposes? I personally use numbers and then & all the values in such cases to get a one line if. Also the List<CheckBoxList> to List<String> is pretty usuless. I imagine you can use link on the checkboxlist to check the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must of had some major brain fart yesterday as this morning it was clear as day.  For some reason when i posted this post i was looking at a selction made from my services checkboxlist when infact all i had to do was look at my browser checkboxlist on another page.  If it was empty dont display otherwise display it.  Can't belive i didnt think of this yesterday.

Wrapped the `div` in:

```
if (Session["Step04Browsers"] != null)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because you seem to mix different session variables.

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly I was using the looking at the wrong session completely.  All I had to do was check if Session["Step04Browsers"] was empty of not.  If it was then don't display it otherwise display it. Check my original post for the HTML fix

Answer (score -1):

You don't even need to store anything in the session you can do this all client side. To get the selected list items you can use:

```
var checked_checkboxes = $("#<%= Services.ClientID %> input:checked")
```

Then you can get the value and text as so:

```
checked_checkboxes.each(function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
     var text = $(this).closest("td").find("label").html();
}); /* You can also use a for loop */
```

I suggest changing

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="Services" CssClass="CheckboxList">
```

to

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="Services" CssClass="CheckboxList" onclick="ChangeCheckBox();">
```

where ChangeCheckBox is a javascript function that gets the selected values as shown above and then hides/shows the div based on what values are selected.

Comment: You haven't read my post correctly and have miss-understood my post, the checkboxes are not on the same page as the `div`. I know how to show/hide if they are on the same page.